# Why is this code not evaluating the winner and console logging the winning message?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Edit: edited to put the correct snippet. The code was different from what I had on my machine, that's why it didn't produce any errors on my end.

I'm trying to build a simple tic toe game using React and i'm new to it.

This is my App.js file.

I'm trying to console.log the message announcing winner per this line

```
 if (winner) {
      console.log(`winner is ${winner}`);
    } else {
      console.log(`now,turn is ${copiedCells[i]}`);
```

It's not console logging the message when the winning combinations are met.
Also the game doesn't end ( = can still click and change the value of the cell) when the winning combinations are met. Relevant code:

```
    if (copiedCells[i] || calculateWinner(cells)) {
      return;
    }
```

I'm assigning the return value of `calculateWinner(cells)` to `winner`, and if `winner` is truthy , i'm console logging the value of `winner` which could be either X or O, or null, or at least that's what I thought I was doing.

Why am I not seeing any console logs?

```
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function Board() {
  // declare states
  const [xTurn, setXTurn] = useState(true);
  const [cells, setCells] = useState(Array(9).fill(null));

  function handleClick(i) {
    const copiedCells = cells.slice();

    if (copiedCells[i] || calculateWinner(cells)) {
      return;
    }

    if (xTurn) {
      // value of each cell
      copiedCells[i] = 'X';
    } else {
      copiedCells[i] = 'O';
    }

    let winner = calculateWinner(cells);
    console.log(winner);
    if (winner) {
      console.log(`winner is ${winner}`);
    } else {
      console.log(`now,turn is ${copiedCells[i]}`);
    }
    setCells(copiedCells);

    setXTurn(!xTurn);
  }
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Cell value={cells[0]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(0)} />
      <Cell value={cells[1]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(1)} />
      <Cell value={cells[2]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(2)} />
      <Cell value={cells[3]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(3)} />
      <Cell value={cells[4]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(4)} />
      <Cell value={cells[5]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(5)} />
      <Cell value={cells[6]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(6)} />
      <Cell value={cells[7]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(7)} />
      <Cell value={cells[8]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(8)} />
    </div>
  );
}

function Cell({ value, onSquareClick }) {
  return (
    <div className="cell" onClick={onSquareClick}>
      {value}
    </div>
  );
}

function calculateWinner(cells) {
  const winningCombo = [
    // these indexes need to have same value
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [2, 4, 6],
  ];

  
  for (let i = 0; i < winningCombo.length; i++) {
    
    const winningLine = winningCombo[i];

    const [a, b, c] = winningLine;
    if (
      cells[a] === cells[b] &&
      cells[b] === cells[c] &&
      cells[a] === cells[c] &&
      cells[a] !== null
    ) {
      
      return cells[a];
    } else return null;
  }
}
```

I tried putting a different way of determining the winning combinations, but as far as I know the combinations are correct. I've been describing each line by line to myself but I cannot spot the problem. There's no error messages.

Comment: Have you done any debugging, like, tracing execution through the `calculateWinner()` function?

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Your `calculateWinner` function isn't even syntactically valid. There's **no way** this ran, let alone without errors.

Comment: @JaredSmith It didn't not give me any errors. I can put a whole code snippet if that's possible. i'm taking a look at what you said now.

Comment: @Pointy had to reinstall react devtools, it wasn't working for some reason. i'm not aware of way to tracing the function, I'll look into it. But it seems like i can't search functions through search bar in the debugging tools.

Comment: @meuly I literally just copy-pasted it into the console in the devtools and it dutifully produces a SyntaxError at your `if` statement with an empty conditional. It doesn't even *parse*, much less *run*. When you go to an expert for advice, and the expert tells you something you did was wrong, be very, **very** sure of your ground before arguing with said expert. Now, maybe you didn't put the same code in your question that you're running locally on your machine, but that is also not something we can help you with: we can only work with what you gave us.

Comment: @JaredSmith That's my bad, I put a wrong code. I'll edit it now.

Comment: @meuly, your `calculateWinner` function's if statement has an else block that returns null, meaning that the loop will never advance to check for winners beyond the first row. Also, your second `calculateWinner` call is being called with the state's `cells`, not the `copiedCells` version that includes the new turn's X/O.

Comment: Downvote removed post edit. I've also voted to reopen. M. Desjardins is correct: move your return null *outside* of your `for` loop

Comment: @M.Desjardins Thanks a lot. This solved the issue. Also it seems like it would've made more sense to call the first `calculateWinner` with `copiedCells` as well instead of `cells`, even though the end result is the same.